# Check convergence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{n^{2}}}-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{8}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Please help me to check convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{n^{2}}}-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{8}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}}\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider the Taylor expansion of the summand about $1/n$ for $n$ large:

$$\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{n^{2}}}-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{8}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}} \approx \left (1 + \frac{7}{2 n^2} \right ) - \left (1 - \frac{8}{3 n^2} \right ) = \frac{37}{16 n^2}$$

Use the comparison test.

Comment: So the series converge, right?

Comment: Yes, but why...?

Comment: because $\frac{37}{16n^2} is < 3\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: Because $\sum (1/n^2)$ converges.  How familiar are you with this stuff?

Comment: I don't know Taylor expansion... But I'm familiar with comparison test and convergence of $\sum(1/n^2)$

Comment: Why don't you search on Taylor expansion.  I have time for quick hints, I cannot teach you a full course of Calc II.

Comment: It's from Calc I course, must be done simpler.

Comment: @Jonny: it can be done in a simpler way, since there are square and cube roots identities which allow one avoid the usage of Taylor expansion. Still, the Taylor expansion method is much more powerful and works on any kind of (smooth enough function), so after learning it, these root identities seem to one more like cheap tricks to keep freshmen busy.. :)

Comment: I know Taylor expansion firmly but it is not easy for me to follow. Could you expand one or two lines, with brief description. Is $f(n)=\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{n^{2}}}-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{8}{n^{2}}}$ and can we expand about a variable point? Also does not $1/n \rightarrow 0$ for large n?

Comment: $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$$ when $x << 1$.

Answer (score 2):

(Presumably with tools from Calc I...) Using the conjugate identities 
$$
\sqrt{a}-1=\frac{a-1}{1+\sqrt{a}},\qquad1-\sqrt[3]{b}=\frac{1-b}{1+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}},
$$
one gets 
$$
\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{n^{2}}}-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{8}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}}=x_n+y_n,
$$
with
$$
x_n=\sqrt{1+a_n}-1=\frac{a_n}{1+\sqrt{1+a_n}},\qquad a_n=\frac{7}{n^2},
$$
and
$$
y_n=1-\sqrt[3]{1-b_n}=\frac{b_n}{1+\sqrt[3]{1-b_n}+(\sqrt[3]{1-b_n})^2},\qquad
b_n=\frac{8}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{n^{3}}.
$$
The rest is easy: when $n\to\infty$, the denominator of $x_n$ is at least $2$ hence $x_n\leqslant\frac12a_n$, likewise the denominator of $y_n$ is at least $1$ hence $y_n\leqslant b_n$. Thus,
$$
0\leqslant x_n+y_n\leqslant\tfrac12a_n+b_n\leqslant\frac{12}{n^2},
$$
since $a_n=\frac7{n^2}$ and $b_n\leqslant\frac8{n^2}$. The series $\sum\limits_n\frac1{n^2}$ converges, hence all this proves that the series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ converges (absolutely).

Answer (score 0):

**Update.** Compare 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{n^{2}}}-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{8}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}}\right)
$$
with the serie
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^a}
$$
for a convenient $a\geq 1$.
Note that if $a_n=\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{n^{2}}}-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{8}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}}\right)$,  $b_n=\frac{1}{n^a}$ and
$$
0<\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}<\infty.
$$
then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n<\infty$ if, only if, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n<\infty$.

Comment: Seems based on a couple of misconceptions (plus possibly some sign errors), starting with the wrong expansion $\sqrt{1+u}=1+\sqrt{u}+o(\sqrt{u})$ when $u\to0$.

Comment: @did I update my answer.